# How to get the anchor tags in the iframe from parent window?

Tags: javascript, html

In my parent window I have one iframe. I want to get the anchor tags present inside the iframe from the parent window. If it is possible please give the suggestion, otherwise please tell why it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your iframe is:

```
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
```

First you need to access its document

```
var iframe_doc = document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument;
```

Now you can work with it.

To get all anchors:

```
var all_anchors = iframe_doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

(You will not be able to do that if the parent and the iframe don't share the same protocol, domain and port due to same origin policy)

Comment: Thanks Yarden.If my parent page is My page and Iframe is Google page.In this case i can't get the tags in iframe(because both are different domain) from the parent.How to achieve this.How to break the same origin policy by using some techniques like prox...etc

Comment: You can download the page (i.e Google page) using your server, and then display it.

Comment: Thanks man.Is it possible Without downloading the page.I mean i want load any sites directly. How to achieve this one.